# QItemDelegate with own editorEvent() handling captures right mouse button clicks I want to receive in QTreeView instead

Tags: qt, mouseevent, event-propagation

I have a `QTreeView` widget that uses a custom `QStyledItemDelegate` class (for this question it's the same as using `QItemDelegate`).

The `QStyledItemDelegate` overrides `editorEvent(...)` in order to handle specific mouse left click events based on what it contains.

I need to expand the tree view to support copying of values (first column is the name, second is the actual styled value - line edit, spinbox, dropdown menu, checkbox) with both Ctrl+C (a `QShortcut` thing) and right clicking on an entry's name (first column).

My plan is to install an event handler in my tree view that will process right mouse button clicks - get the current index that is selected, get the value, convert it to a string and send it to the `QClipboard`.

**Problem:** before loading the model, that is my tree view is empty, my event handler is detecting right mouse button clicks without any issues. However once the model has been loaded it's the delegate that takes over the mouse in terms of clicks. I found out that by observing my debug logs in both the `eventFilter(...)` of my event handler as well as those inside the `editorEvent(...)` of my delegate.

Here is my `eventFilter(...)` for the event handler that I install using the `installEventFilter(...)` of my tree view:

```
auto MouseKeyPressFilter::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) -> bool
{
    qDebug() << "Mouse event filter activated";
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {
        qDebug() << "Mouse event filter: right button released";
        auto mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::RightButton)
        {
            qDebug() << "Pressed with right button";
            event->accept();
        }

        return QObject::eventFilter(watched, event);
    }
    else
    {
        // When model has been loaded, MouseButtonRelease are no longer processed and this
        // message occurs 
        qDebug() << "Mouse event filter: not related to button release event";

        return QObject::eventFilter(watched, event);
    }
}
```

The delegate's `editorEvent(...)` looks like this:

```
auto CustomizedItemDelegate::editorEvent(QEvent* event, QAbstractItemModel* model, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) -> bool
{
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);

    // Added this debugging purposes!
    if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        qDebug() << "Delegate received right mouse click";
    }

    // Handling of left mouse button clicks
    if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        // Process left mouse button clicks based on what value the delegate stores
        // ...

        case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
        {
            // ...
            event->accept();
            return true;
        }
        case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
        {
            // ...
            event->accept();
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

I had a 1 year gap from my last coding experience so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here in terms of event propagation.

Comment: If you have found the solution then do not place it as an edition of your question, instead publish it in the answers section.

Comment: @eyllanesc Nope. In particular I'm interested why the way I'm doing it doesn't work. There are probably other workarounds beside the one I've added as an update.